# How to pan/zoom while QInputDialog

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm iterating over a layer with a python-script in QGIS 2.18. I am going to pan to every feature and ask the user a question regarding this feature an do something depending on his answer.
How is it possible to enable user-pan/zoom etc. while QInputDialog waits for an answer ?
Do I have to use other dialogs to be able to pan/zoom while looking for an answer?

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
pLayer=QgsVectorLayer(r'pathToSHP', "polygonLayer","ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([pLayer])
for po in pLayer.getFeatures():
    pLayer.select(po.id())
    qgis.utils.iface.actionPanToSelected().trigger()
    pLayer.deselect(po.id())
    checked = False
    while not checked:
        answer=QInputDialog.getText(None,'...','....')
        if answer[0] in ('Y','y'): 
          #doSomething
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code seems to do your requirement:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QInputDialog

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()

pLayer = QgsVectorLayer(r'/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp', 
                        "polygonLayer",
                        "ogr")

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(pLayer)

for i, po in enumerate(pLayer.getFeatures()):
    pLayer.select(po.id())
    canvas.zoomToSelected()
    answer = QInputDialog.getText(None,'Dialog','Answer:')
    pLayer.deselect(po.id())

    if answer[0] in ('Y','y'):
        print i + 1, po.attributes()
    elif answer[0] in ('N','n'):
        print i + 1, "nothing to do"   
    else:
        break  #to exit loop

canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
```

It iterates over a layer to pan/zoom every feature while **QInputDialog** waits for an answer. However, I don't know why is it necessary to have one loaded layer to zoom first feature.

After running it at Python Console of QGIS I got this (however, with whatever loaded layer it zooms to first feature as it expected):

[image]

Putting **y** in **Answer** field and click in **OK**, it results in zoom to second feature and it's printed attributes for first feature at Python Console.

[image]

Putting **n** in **Answer** field and click in **OK**, it results in zoom to third feature and it's printed "nothing to do" for second feature at Python Console.

[image]

Finally, after answering "yes" for remaining features it was printed remaining attributes at Python Console and Map Canvas returned to "Full Extent"; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

Comment: My script will be used to detect digitizing mistakes in input data. It compares the valid cadastral map with partially invalid input data depending on a threshold . In this input-dataset the parcels are devided into smaller pieces (landuse).  The script recognizes missing vertices and digitized vertices beside valid vertices.

Comment: A zoom to the feature causes mostly a to small scale to be able how to decide to apply or discard the suggested changes. A zoom to the digitized or parcel-feature will mostly cause to large scales to check the mistake in detail. It will be useful to be able pan/zoom while the decision-process in order to get an overview of the specific feature to check the issues in various scales/positions. Your suggested script didn't enable the opportunity to pan / zoom during every decision.

Comment: (Missing/wrong vertices are stored as lines of suggested vertice-displacements. I'm iterating over this line-features and ask the user to apply or discard the suggested changes)

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding of your question, you want to be able to use QGIS MainWindow while your QInputDialog is open on top of the application.

To perform that you need to set your Dialog in a non-modal (modeless) mode.

A modal Dialog will block the Ui until the user close the dialog.

A non-modal (modeless) Dialog will let the user continue to use the main application even if the dialog is still open.

Some nice resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969319/popup-non-modal-in-line-dialog-in-pyqt?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309803/pyqt-non-modal-dialog-always-modal) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211490/how-to-make-a-non-blocking-non-modal-qmessagebox)

For example to create a non-modal Inputdialog from Qgis python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog

my_dialog = QInputDialog(iface.mainWindow())
my_dialog.setModal(False) # so we keep UI alive and accessible
my_dialog.show()
```

Starting from this snippet, you should be able to configure your Input dialog as needed!